# After react-native eject. iOS shows there is no index.js

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make app with react first time. I've created my app using

```
create-react-native-app applicatin
```

Once i've finished my job with JS side. i did:

```
react-native eject
```

After eject. I've opened the iOS build with XCode and build & run shows:

```
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

with red screen on simulator:

```
Failed to load bundle (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error: (Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/user/AppDir/application"])
```

There is no index.js or index related file in my application directory. 
How can i bring index.js? What does it do? Why am i missing this file?

Comment: What error shown on the red screen?

Comment: ```Failed to load bundle (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle? platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error: (Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/user/AppDir/application"])```

Comment: What is the output of `create-react-native-app` command? If it ends well, it should be displaying `Happy hacking`.

Comment: Yes it displays ```Happy hacking```

Comment: If it displays Happy Hacking, the `index.js` should be created in the folder. Please try to run the command with another name, and check **before** ejecting your app.

Comment: Try 'react-native init ProjectName' when you want to start a project without depended on Expo. This should create your index.js file in your project folder.

Comment: This happened to me one day at the command-line, on a project that has been building fine for several months. We always build from cli since we use automated cloud CI. I eventually just blew away the `node_modules` sub-dir and started afresh.